# Increase particular letter size in html

Tags: html

I want to increase **C** and **I** . I also use `::first-text{}`. It works Now, how can i increase **I**.

```
<p>Creating  and  Implementing</p>

<center>
<p style="font-size: 32px;color: #424242;margin-top: 15px;font-family:Rockwell; ">
    <style>
       p::first-letter{
       font-size:40px;
                      }                           
    </style>

  <span class="a">Creating</span> <span>and</span> <span>Implementing</span> 
     </p>
</center>
```

Comment: You can't with pure CSS. You can add those words in a `span` element and then capitalize just them. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aszbbdt1/)

Comment: Are you stating that `:first-text` works for you? (it shouldn't because it doesn't exist) Are you asking something...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple, You have to change you p tags like

```
<p>
   <span class="highlight-first-letter"><b style="font-size:20px;">C</b>reating</span> <span>and</span> <span class="highlight-first-letter"><b style="font-size:20px;">I</b>mplementing</span> 
</p>
```

your output is look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `first-text`, but `first-letter` should work for the **C**.

For the **I**, you would have to wrap it in a span and give it a class unfortunately.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-first-letter

--Update--

I'm not sure if you aware, but `style` tags are not 'scoped'.  This means that **all** `<p>` tags will have their first letters increased, is this what you want?

Also, the `center` tag is deprecated and should not be used.

```
<style>
p{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #424242;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-family:Rockwell; 
}
.highlight-first-letter::first-letter{
       font-size:40px;
       display: inline-block;
}                           
</style>
<p>    
  <span class="highlight-first-letter">Creating</span> <span>and</span> <span class="highlight-first-letter">Implementing</span> 
     </p>
```

Comment: Sorry. It was first-letter.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you feel this is correct

Comment: Thanks for your ans. but it does't show any result.

Comment: apologies - the span must be `display: inline-block`.  I've updated the answer now

Answer (score -1):

i have done it with  jquery it can be achieved also in javascript by`document.getelementbyid`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=o>c js isj kl</div>
<script>
var txt = $('#o').text();
var new_text = txt.replace(/i/gi, 'I') ;

$('#o').text(new_text.replace(/c/gi,'C'));
</script>
```

**after your update i havev found that in css**

introduce span in between your text

```
 <p>Creating  and  Implementing</p>

    <center>
    <p style="font-size: 32px;color: #424242;margin-top: 15px;font-family:Rockwell; ">
        <style>
           p::first-letter{
           font-size:40px;
                          }       
          .l::first-letter{
            font-size:40px
}                    
        </style>

      <span class="a">Creating</span> <span>and</span> <span class=l>Implementing</span> 
         </p>
    </center>
```

Comment: just down-voting this as your jQuery would replace **all** I's and C's

Comment: yeah but if he want to aviod it he should use `span` or `strong ` between the letters